# How to store data in hstore data type with multiple keys and values rails 5

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, hstore

views/_form.html.erb

```
Extra fee field name : <%= text_field_tag :extra_fee_field,nil, placeholder: 'Enter field name',name: "payment_plan[payment_fees[extra_fee_field]][]" %>fees 
Extra fee value : <%= text_field_tag :extra_fee_value,nil, placeholder: 'Enter fee value in %',name: "payment_plan[payment_fees[extra_fee_value]][]" %> %
<%= submit_tag "Add",id: "add" %>
```

controllers/payment_plan_controller.rb

```
def create
@payment_plan = PaymentPlan.new(payment_plan_params)
@payment_plan.save
```

end

```
private
def payment_plan_params
    params.require(:payment_plan).permit(:pay_within_days,:display_active,
    :payment_fees=>[:extra_fee_field=>[],:extra_fee_value=>[]])
end
```

model/payment_plan.rb

```
class PaymentPlan < ApplicationRecord
store_accessor :payment_fees
end
```

Data store in below format:-

payment_fees: {"extra_fee_field"=>"[\"serfere\", \"sfsdfdff\"]", "extra_fee_value"=>"[\"5\", \"7\"]"}, display_active: false, created_at: "2016-07-12 06:41:48", updated_at: "2016-07-12 06:41:48">

please help me.
Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying my best i get the solutions all above code is correct just change in method of controller

```
@extra_fee_field = params[:payment_plan][:payment_fees][:extra_fee_field]
@extra_fee_value = params[:payment_plan][:payment_fees][:extra_fee_value]
@payment_plan[:payment_fees] = @extra_fee_field.zip(@extra_fee_value).to_h
```

After this i can store data in hstore data type